# Take a received feedback item, turn it into a post

Tags: posts, customization

Using a feedback form post, user submitted feedback appears in the settings pages under `<blogname>.wordpress.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=feedback.`

I would like to then take those posts (with a manual step - I'd like to vet them first), and post them otherwise as is (at least usually) as posts.

How would I do that?